# Why does my render layer node not have the expected number of outputs?

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes

I should get this type of box when I go to compositing mode. I have seen this tutorial from youtube (Blender Guru) but the box I'm getting is different. Here is the picture box in the mean the name render layer.

[image]

[image]

[image: ender]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Box"? Are you referring to the sidebar with the *Node* and *Properties* panel?

Comment: sorry just i have edited question

Answer (score 3):

Enabling this will give you all the extra input (e.g. Noisy Image, Denoising Normal...)

[image: Denoise data]